# React and global state

Tags: reactjs, redux

suppose i have an aplication which depends on authentication

i was using context-api (react) for this so all components which need user details and related functions have access to it

now where do i specify the <Context.Provider /> ?

the problem is that the way gatsby works is it has pages, not like a root app under which all routes fall like react

so what i did is have a  component of sorts which is like a wrapper for all pages, which gives all pages the same styling and the context

so now all pages have access to user

but here is the issue - all pages still dont access the same global state

i.e. suppose i go from contact-page to say blogs-page, the provider is "rerun"

what happens if the provider reruns everytime i migrate to a new page ?

the useEffect reruns, which fetches the user yet again

context

```
export const AuthContext = createContext();
    
export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    
  // HERE LIES THE PROBLEM...THIS WILL BE RUN EVERYTIME I GO TO A NEW PAGE
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((userSnapshot) => {
      if (userSnapshot) {
        setUser({ email: userSnapshot.email });
      }
      setLoading(false);
    });
  return unsubscribe;
  }, []);
    
  const values = { loading, user, signup, signin, signout };
    
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={values}>
          {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

layout

```
export const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Container>
       <AuthContextProvider>
         <Header />
         {children}
       </AuthContextProvider>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
};
```

pages

```
export const AnyPage = () => {
  const context = useContext(AuthContext);
    return (
      <Layout>
        {context.user && <p>i am groot</p>}        
      </Layout>
    );
}
```

now i assume the same would happen, be it redux etc anything -

everytime i go to a new page, the hydration of state will happen again...

am i making a very dumb mistake....

Comment: Did you see official guide: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/tutorial/authentication-tutorial/

Comment: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/routing/client-only-routes-and-user-authentication/ (i never knew dynamic pages like react are possible in gatsby, sorry for my ignorance..now the same redux, context, etc wrapper goes to all components)
however, i just changed my observer pattern and dont calll in useffect, and just attempt to fetch the user on login / signup and store the user in local-storage, like in the link provided by @bravemaster